# js page re-direct on button submit not working with IE or Edge

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, redirect, button, microsoft-edge

I have a fieldset for data input.  When changes on a page are complete, a submit button is used to save the changes and redirect back to the index page.  My problem is that the js-based redirect back to the main index page does not work in IE or Edge browsers. The input fields are saved ok.  I've tried everything I know of and everything I can find posted online without success.

Here is the submit button code:

```
<input type="button" name="Done" class="saveField action-button" value="Submit" />
```

Here is the button js submit code:

```
$(".submit").click(function() {

saveDetails();

})
```

And here is the saveDetails code with the redirect back to the index page (admin.php):

```
function saveDetails() {

form = "msform";

$.ajax({

    url : 'classes/Process.php?page=saveDetails',

    async : true,

    type : 'post',

    data : $('form#' + form).serialize(),

    success : function(data) {


        //location.reload();

        $("#recstatus").val("edit");

        window.location.assign("admin.php");

    },

    fail : function() {

        // showPleaseWait(false);

    },

    error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {

        // showPleaseWait(false);

    }

});

}
```

Everything works ok except the redirect.  Here's what I've tried so far:

```
window.location.assign("admin.php");
window.location.replace("admin.php");
location.assign = "admin.php";
location.replace = "admin.php";
location.href = "admin.php";
window.location.assign('/admin.php');
window.location.assign('FULL HTTP ADDRESS URL');
```

As stated previously, the input data is processed ok, it is only the redirect that isn't working in IE11 or edge.  And the redirect works fine with Safari, Chrome, and Firefox.

Any suggestions will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.  There is nothing wrong with the window.location.assign redirect. The problem is that the machine+browser is slow and the previous location.reload had not finished yet ...and of course js execution is asynchronous.

The fix for me is to simply remove the location.reload call.  It was written for an obsolete save button call that reloaded the page to verify that all the input fields had been updated.  The new submit button updates the fields and returns the user to the form index page, so the location.reload is pointless/obsolete.

I commented the line out in the code above, so this is now a working example.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
window.location.assign('/admin.php');
```

hope it helps.

Comment: thx, but no luck. It worked fine in all the non- IE/edge browsers and had no effect at all on the IE edge browsers. It's like the redirect command is invisible to them